# debugging multiple threads with visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo

I am setting some breakpoints in some `async` threaded code and I can't seem to figure out how to tell visual studio code to catch any threads in this code path.

```
fn main() {
  println!("hello world"); // hits this line when I set a breakpoint
  readTheFeed("https://www.coindesk.com/arc/outboundfeeds/rss/?outputType=xml");
}

async fn readTheFeed(feed_url: &str) -> Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> {
  let content = reqwest::get(feed_url) //doesn't hit any breakpoints in the async code
      .await?
      .bytes()
      .await?;
  let channel = Channel::read_from(&content[..])?;
  println!("{}", channel.title.to_string());
  println!("{}", channel.description.to_string());
  Ok(channel)
}
```

How do I tell visual studio code to break with any threads that hit this piece of code?

EDIT ----

I updated the code as aync task are "inert" meaning they don't run unless passed to an executer. Here's the updated code:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  let t = readTheFeed("https://www.coindesk.com/arc/outboundfeeds/rss/?outputType=xml");
  block_on(t);
}

async fn readTheFeed(feed_url: &str) -> Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> {
  let content = reqwest::get(feed_url)
      .await?
      .bytes()
      .await?;
  let channel = Channel::read_from(&content[..])?;
  println!("{}", channel.title.to_string());
  println!("{}", channel.description.to_string());
  Ok(channel)
}
```

Now I am getting the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime', /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.17.0/src/runtime/context.rs:21:19
```

Comment: Async code is not necessarily multi-thread, and I've found that it is easiear to debug if you disable the MT thing (`tokio::basic_scheduler`, for example). But are not driving the future returned by `readTheFeed()` so your code does nothing, maybe that is why you do not hit the breakpoint?

Comment: After your edit, why do you use `block_on` instead of simply `await`ing `readTheFeed`? (Actually I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate for that point somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  println!("hello world"); // hits this line when I set a breakpoint
  readTheFeed("https://www.coindesk.com/arc/outboundfeeds/rss/?outputType=xml").await;
}

async fn readTheFeed(feed_url: &str) -> Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> {
  let content = reqwest::get(feed_url) //doesn't hit any breakpoints in the async code
      .await?
      .bytes()
      .await?;
  let channel = Channel::read_from(&content[..])?;
  println!("{}", channel.title.to_string());
  println!("{}", channel.description.to_string());
  Ok(channel)
}
```

The problem is that this line:

```
readTheFeed("https://www.coindesk.com/arc/outboundfeeds/rss/?outputType=xml");
```

is just creating a future and immediately dropping it without running it. In order to run the future, you need an executor (which I provide with `#[tokio::main]`, but there are other ways if you need more control) and then to `await` (or [`spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html)) the future.

Comment: The function doesn't return a `Future<T>` but a `Result<Channel, Error>` object.

Comment: @SomethingsGottaGive the function is `async` so it returns a `Future<Result<Channel, Error>>` (that's what `async` does: it wraps the function and its return value in a `Future`).

Comment: You can check this with the Simpson test: `let _:() = readTheFeed("https://www.coindesk.com/arc/outboundfeeds/rss/?outputType=xml");` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=89312f388b623d98694ed01346181973)): the error message tells you the real type of the returned value.

Comment: I am still getting an error with your code - I don't get it.

Comment: Apart from the missing `Channel` struct (and the missing `async` for `main`), this code does work: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=73676f5bccbab5a7807c703676e25d1a)